# System.Runtime.Caching Configuration via Code?

Tags: wcf, caching, memory, configuration

```
MemoryCache.Default.CacheMemoryLimit = 10;
```

CacheMemoryLimit has no programmatic "setter", but is apparently set in the config file.

Can anyone recommend a way to actually set the memory limit to 10mb in code?

This is for a WCF service with a database-driven configuration, so rows in a table manage the behavior of different parts of the code. That allows central administration of many sites/apps, so I need help figuring this out.

Thanks.